# Handling mutable variables in multiple functions in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to do Kotlin in Android but I have some issues with mutables. Let's say I'm doing a `TextView` that's accessed across multiple methods.

```
var tv: TextView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    tv = find(R.id.tv)
}

fun clearText(){
    tv?.setText("")
}

fun setText(text: String) {
    tv?.setText(text)
}
```

This works, but having `tv?` every time I use the TextView is a code smell. Is there a better way of doing this? I feel like I should be using `val` instead of `var` but I can't find a way to put it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways I know of to solve this. [Lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) and [Kotlin's Android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).

Lateinit lets you assign a value to a non-null type later in the classes lifespan.

```
lateinit var textView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
  textView = findViewById(R.id.view_text)
}
```

You can now access it without a null check.

Or, you can use Kotlin's extensions.

Add the plugin to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And import the generated accessors into your Activity, Fragment or whatever.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_name.*

text_view_id.text = "Hello World!"
```